# Why is my output order seemingly random (action script 3.0)?

Tags: java, actionscript, for-loop, output

```
var personTab:Object=new Object()  
personTab.firstName='John'  
personTab.lastName='Appleseed'  
personTab.age=18  
for(var A:String in personTab)  
{  

    trace(A+': '+personTab[A])  
}
```

> Output order is lastName, firstName, age. What I don't understand is why it's not firstName, lastName, age. Also, if i change the name of the variable 'A' to say 'foo' the order changes to firstName, age, lastName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects in ActionScript are unordered, essentially you can think of them as a hash-table or associative array in which the values are referenced by their key (see [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html)). If the order is important to you you should use an array or, if you also need the ability to look-up values by key, create your own custom collection which preserves the order.